# How do you write a toString() method for an int array for object oriented programming?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, tostring

How do you write an toString() method for an int array? Say to return the string representation of a 52 card pack?

Here is an example array as part of a class:

```
{
    int[] cards = new int[52];

    public void Deck()
    {
        // Setting up array
        String[] suits = {"SPADES", "CLUBS", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS"};
        String[] ranks = {"TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", 
            "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE"};
        {
            // Initalising array
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
            {
                cards[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is being done in an object oriented manner. How would a toString() method be written in this case in order to return a string representation of the pack of cards or in this case, the array?

I have currently used:

```
@Overide
public String toString()
{
    return getClass().getName() + "[cards[]= " + cards[] + "]";
}
```

I have also used a similar toString() method written as:

```
return getClass().getName() + "[suits[]= " + suits[] + "ranks[]= " + ranks[] + "]";
```

It's the same kind of toString() method I have used for other values and it normally works. Though now I get this error for both (or at least, the first one):

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: Class cards //which I dont have other than the array at the top
location: Class Pack // The class the array is currently in

unexpected type
required: value
found: class

'.class.' expected
```

As for printing it, I want it either formatted as a list, or a grid.

Comment: Instead of using Strings I would use `enum` for the suit and the face value. A card would be a combination and this would make printing it easier.  BTW Your IDE can generate a `toString()` for you if you use this pattern.

Comment: @SeanOwen see the edit at the top, I just want a standard string representation in the form of a list or grid.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have already used suit and rank as enums in a seperate class that is within the same package, but they have been taliored to intergers, not strings.

Comment: Every `enum` has a `name()` method which is the String representation of the name.  How did you use `enum` without Strings?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well, I didn't have a `name()` method in the `enum` methods themselves. All they had was `int values` and the means to return them as in `getValue()`. I do use things like `DIAMONDS(1)` but thats as far it goes. Do you want me to put up one of my enums?

Comment: @SIHB007 Like I said "Every `enum` has a `name()`" method as it inherits from `Enum` which has a `name()` method whether you overrode it or not.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--

Comment: @SIHB007 it is not possible to remove the `name()` method from an `enum`, it is there whether you like it or not.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Apologies I didn't notice 'inherited' then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it more OOPish, you should create a new class `Card`.

The `Card` class will have to fields `suit`, and `rank` (the type could be an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) here).

Make sure `Card` overwrites `toString()`, and make sure your array in `Deck` is `Card[]` (and NOT `int[]`).

Now you can easily implement `toString()` by invoking [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])), which will in its turn invoke the `toString()` of each `Card` object, resulting in the required representation of your deck.

---

As for your code (which was added later):

```
return getClass().getName() + "[cards[]= " + cards[] + "]";
```

Will not compile because `cards[]` is not a value - `cards` is, but it will not get you what you want. Array's `toString()` does NOT produce the content of the `array, and you should use Arrays.toString(cards)`.

However, I suggest redesigning the code as described at the head of this answer.

Comment: I don't really have time to redesign the whole code, but I have inserted `Arrays.toString(cards)` and I no longer have any errors. I might insert a means of printing out the array into the toString() method to finish it off.